# Oracle - Generate Package.Procedure call

Tags: oracle, package, execution

Good morning guys,
do you know an easy way to automatically generate an Oracle package.procedure call?

After have defined the package

```
 Create Or Replace Package PKG1
    As
    Procedure PRC1
        (
            P_VAL1_I        In  NUMBER,
            P_Return_Set_O  Out Sys_Refcursor,
        );
    End;
```

I'd like to generate via a script the call

```
 DECLARE
         var_P_RETURN_SET_O SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
         PKG1.PRC1(P_VAL1_I => 0, P_Return_Set_O => var_P_RETURN_SET_O );
    END;
```

Of Course I'll replace later the input parameter(s).

Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: What is your question? You call the procedure, what else do you need?

Comment: The question is .. how i can programmatically generate the calling code?

Comment: You question is still not clear. You want to call a procedure, then you must write a line which executes it. What do you like? Click on a button which calls the procedure? If yes, the write code to draw such button an call the procedure when it is clicked - but still you have to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here the answer to myself .. was not that difficult .. simply run a pl/sql that build the procedure call .

```
Declare
    l_Package varchar2(255) :=upper('xxxxxxxxx');
    l_Proc varchar2(255) :=upper('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
Begin
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('DECLARE');
    For Var_Out In (
        select ObjArg.Argument_Name,Data_type
            FROM sys.user_objects UsrObj 
            Inner Join sys.user_arguments ObjArg On UsrObj.object_id= ObjArg.object_id
            Where UsrObj.object_name = l_Package
            And ObjArg.ObjecT_Name= l_Proc
           AND UsrObj.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
           And ObjArg.In_Out='OUT'
          )
    Loop
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('L_'||Var_Out.Argument_Name ||' '||Var_Out.Data_type||';');
    end Loop;
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('BEGIN');
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(l_Package||'.'||l_Proc);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('(');
    For PArams In (
        select ObjArg.Argument_Name,Data_type,ObjArg.In_Out
            FROM sys.user_objects UsrObj 
            Inner Join sys.user_arguments ObjArg On UsrObj.object_id= ObjArg.object_id
            Where UsrObj.object_name = l_Package
            And ObjArg.ObjecT_Name= l_Proc
           AND UsrObj.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
          )
    Loop
        IF PArams.In_Out='OUT' Then
            Dbms_Output.Put_Line(PArams.Argument_Name || '=> L_'||PArams.Argument_Name);
        ELSE
            Dbms_Output.Put_Line(PArams.Argument_Name || '=> xxx');
        End If;
    end Loop;
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(');');
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('END');
End;
```

Result ..

```
DECLARE
  L_P_RETURN_SET_O REF CURSOR;
  L_P_EXECUTION_STATUS_O NUMBER;
BEGIN
  PKG.PROC
  (
    P_PARAM_I=> xxx
    P_RETURN_SET_O=> L_P_RETURN_SET_O
  );
END;
```

The code is not perfect ..but it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec PKG1.PRC1(0, :rc);
print rc;
```

Comment: yes .. but eachtime I need to "write" the code .. checking the in/out parameters .. I'm searching that generate the code ...

Comment: Did you explore `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in this, you can supply your query as string.

Comment: using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE I need to pass the procedure call statement .. I do not want each time type the code ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create job which will call your procedure on specified intervals.

For instance:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'JOB_NAME'
      ,start_date      =>  SYSDATE
      ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=05;BYMINUTE=00;BYSECOND=00'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
      ,job_action      =>  'BEGIN
                             PKG1.PRC1(P_VAL1_I => 0, P_Return_Set_O => var_P_RETURN_SET_O );
                            END;
      ,comments        => 'JOB_NAME'
    );
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(name => 'JOB_NAME');
END;
```

This job will run daily at 5 a.m .

I hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for :( I'm looking for an automatic way to generate the code to execute ..